# Colorama and Pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, colorama

here is my problem : I wrote a python bot that makes plenty of stuff, including printing colorful text for better understanding. I'm using the colorama package because it prints color even on windows command prompt.
Here is how I use colorama, which work both on unix and windows using python 3.8 :

```
from colorama import Fore, init
init()
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
```

Now my goal is to transform my script into a .exe so it can run on windows without any install. Problem is, using pyinstaller.exe --onefile script.py, or pyinstaller.exe --onedir script.py or whatever, I can't make it work. Pyinstaller builds a EXE successfully with 0 error message, but whenever I launch the exe I get :
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'`
and it's the only module missing. I've searched through the entire internet, and didn't manage to fix that by myself. You guys are my last hope ! please help me

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --hidden-import colorama script.py
```

This (--hidden-import colorama) should ensure that pyinstaller builds the application including colorama.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Unfortunaly I already tried this,  (did it again just to be sure)
but it doesn't work.
import colorama
doesnt work either on a normal file

Answer (score 0):

you should run `pip/pipenv install colorama` at first.